UDP Broadcast на C# работает только на машине, которая его запустила
Есть следующий тестовый код хоста:
            string localIP = IP.ToString();

            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
            udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;

            IPEndPoint broadcastEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), 11000);

            try
            {
                var counter = 0;
                while (counter < 5)
                {
                    byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(localIP);

                    udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, broadcastEndPoint);
                    counter++;
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                udpClient.Close();
            }

И следующий код для клиента:
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11000);
        string receivedData = null;
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint receiveEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
                byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref receiveEndPoint);

                receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                Console.WriteLine("Received broadcast from {0} : {1}\n",
                    receiveEndPoint.ToString(),
                    receivedData);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            udpClient.Close();
        }

При запуске хоста и клиента на одной машине, всё работает корректно и пакеты доходят до клиента. Однако после того, как я попробовал запустить их на разных машинах, подключенных к одной локальной сети (в качестве локальной сети выступил режим модема на телефоне), пакеты доходить перестали. Брандмауэр на обоих машинах отключен, так что понятия не имею, в чем может быть проблема
Пробовал отправлять рассылку на меньший диапазон (192.255.255.255), однако это тоже не помогло. При попытке дебага клиента, дебаггер останавливается и программа перестает подавать какие-либо признаки жизни на строке receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes). Надеюсь, кто-то сможет подсказать решение

Видимо broadcast пакеты не пересылаются в таком режиме. Наверное в этом можно убедиться с помощью wireshark (вообще, broadcast без проблем работал в локальной сети в те старые времена, когда ethernet пакеты реально ходили  по одному коаксиальному кабелю (т.е. еще до появления хабов, свитчей и проч. оборудования такого рода))

У режима модема может работать изоляция клиентов. Вы хоть пинг попробовали, чтобы убедиться что связь в принципе между клиентами локальной сети есть?

Попробовал ping и пакеты правда не доходят, но тогда возникает вопрос, есть ли какой-то способ использовать локальную сеть, созданную через режим модема, чтобы пакеты всё-таки доходили
Исправлено: Попробовал отключить брандмауэр, через ping пакеты по локальной сети идут

В режиме модема на андроиде комп изолирован от программ андроида.

@quantum32043 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Я нашел решение проблемы. Как оказалось, broadcast IP нужно было высчитывать для каждой используемой локальной сети по отдельности. Я просто получаю адрес локальной сети, ее маску, по ним высчитываю broadcast IP для этой сети и на него шлю UDP пакеты.
Код хоста:
IPEndPoint broadcastEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Tools.GetBroadcastAddress(IP.ToString(), Tools.GetLocalMask().ToString()), 11000);
        try
        {
            ClientsWaiting = true;
            while (ClientsWaiting)
            {
                byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IP.ToString());
             udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, broadcastEndPoint);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            udpClient.Close();
        }

Код методов для получения адреса:
static class Tools
{
    public static IPAddress GetLocalAddress()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var networkInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            var items = networkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
                .Where(x => x.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork && IsInLocalRange(x.Address));
            result.AddRange(items.Select(ip => ip.Address.ToString()));
        }

        return IPAddress.Parse(result.Last());

        bool IsInLocalRange(IPAddress address)
        {
            byte[] bytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
            return bytes[0] == 192 && bytes[1] == 168;
        }
    }

    public static IPAddress GetLocalMask()
    {
        List<string> mask = new List<string>();
        foreach (var networkInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            var items = networkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
                .Where(x => x.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork && IsInLocalRange(x.Address));
            mask.AddRange(items.Select(ip => ip.IPv4Mask.ToString()));
        }

        return IPAddress.Parse(mask.Last());

        bool IsInLocalRange(IPAddress address)
        {
            byte[] bytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
            return bytes[0] == 192 && bytes[1] == 168;
        }
    }
    public static IPAddress GetBroadcastAddress(string ipAddress, string subnetMask)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(subnetMask))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("IP address and subnet mask cannot be null or empty");
        }

        byte[] ipBytes = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress).GetAddressBytes();
        byte[] maskBytes = IPAddress.Parse(subnetMask).GetAddressBytes();

        if (ipBytes.Length != maskBytes.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid IP address or subnet mask format");
        }

        byte[] broadcastBytes = new byte[ipBytes.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < broadcastBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            broadcastBytes[i] = (byte)(ipBytes[i] | (byte)~maskBytes[i]);
        }

        return new IPAddress(broadcastBytes);
    }
}

Код клиента:
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11000);
        udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
        string receivedData = null;

            IPEndPoint receiveEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref receiveEndPoint);

            receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

            Console.WriteLine($"Received broadcast from {receiveEndPoint.ToString()} : {receivedData}\n");
        }


Отлично, а как именно высчитываете? Покажите пример. Ответ можно редактировать.

@aepot дополнил ответ
